# Find key by inner map value in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Let's suppose i have:

`%{apple: %{color: red, id: 1}, pear: %{color: green, id: 2}}`

What is fastest way to get key (apple, for example) looping by value (ex, color: red)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to add an answer to provide some diversity. Comprehensions are good but can be clunky when trying to pipe/chain operations. Another solution might be to use [`Stream.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Stream.html#filter/2) and [`Stream.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Stream.html#map/2)

```
red = :red

fruits
|> Stream.filter(&match?({_fruit, %{color: ^red}}, &1))
|> Stream.map(&elem(&1, 0))
|> Enum.to_list()
```

You could then expand on this to create better composition than you would get from a typical comprehension **IF** you wanted to filter by different and/or multiple parameters. For example, you could write a module like this:

```
defmodule FruitSearch do
  @fruits %{
    apple: %{color: :red, taste: :tart},
    banana: %{color: :yellow, taste: :sweet},
    lemon: %{color: :yellow, taste: :sour}
  }

  @spec query_fruits(%{
          optional(:color) => atom,
          optional(:taste) => atom
        }) :: [atom]
  def query_fruits(params) do
    @fruits
    |> maybe_filter_by_color(params)
    |> maybe_filter_by_taste(params)
    |> Stream.map(&elem(&1, 0))
    |> Enum.to_list()
  end

  defp maybe_filter_by_color(enum, %{color: color}) do
    Stream.filter(enum, &match?({_fruit, %{color: ^color}}, &1))
  end

  defp maybe_filter_by_color(enum, _params) do
    enum
  end

  defp maybe_filter_by_taste(enum, %{taste: taste}) do
    Stream.filter(enum, &match?({_fruit, %{taste: ^taste}}, &1))
  end

  defp maybe_filter_by_taste(enum, _params) do
    enum
  end
end
```

Examples:

```
iex> FruitSearch.query_fruits(%{color: :yellow})
[:banana, :lemon]

iex> FruitSearch.query_fruits(%{taste: :sour, color: :yellow})
[:lemon]

iex> FruitSearch.query_fruits(%{})
[:lemon, :banana, :apple]
```

The solution mainly depends on the use-case. If you don't need something this complex, comprehensions are a great solution.

Comment: Proposing `Stream`-based solution for the explicitly stated “What is **fastest** way to [...]” question is weird. `Stream`s are way slower than iterations.

Comment: I would strongly advise against designing for pipe-ability first. The code in this example is overly complex for what OP is trying to solve, and as Aleksei comment correctly states, the stream based solution would very likely not beat one based on a simple comprehension as Brett's answer shows.

Answer (score 8):

[Comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html) make filtering/mapping easy:

```rb
iex> red = :red
:red
iex> green = :green
:green
iex> fruits = %{apple: %{color: red, id: 1}, pear: %{color: green, id: 2}}
%{apple: %{color: :red, id: 1}, pear: %{color: :green, id: 2}}
iex> for {fruit, %{color: ^red}} <- fruits, do: fruit
[:apple]
```

We can take advantage of maps being enumerable (as `{key, value}` pairs) to select all the keys where the value matches some pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum.filter(enumerable, fun)` can be used to filter the map here. As the [doc](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) says, it filters the enumerable, i.e. returns only those elements for which fun returns a truthy value. What we get after using `filter/2` on the map is a keyword list like this: `[a: 1, b: 2]` from which we extract the keys using `Keyword.keys/1`.

```
fruits = %{apple: %{color: "red", id: 1}, pear: %{color: "green", id: 2}}

fruits
|> Enum.filter(&match?({_fruit, %{color: "red"}}, &1))
|> Keyword.keys()
```

This example also show the `match?/2` macro, that allows us to use a pattern match for various predicate functions, but as such it would be faster to use a comprehension for this case as we can filter and return the correct value in one pass.

```
fruits = %{apple: %{color: "red", id: 1}, pear: %{color: "green", id: 2}}

for {hit, %{color: "red"}} <- fruits, do: hit
```